# Histograma de Datas no GGPLOT

Tags: r, data, ggplot2

Não estou conseguindo realizar o ggplot da seguinte tabela:

```
 Data           Frequência
1 2016-06-11        3126
2 2016-03-05         218
3 2016-01-23         431
4 2016-06-04         145
5 2016-11-30         331
6 2016-15-01         275
```

Através do seguinte código:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(Frequência)) + geom_histogram()
```

Dando o seguinte aviso `stat_bin() using bins = 30. Pick better value with binwidth`

O formato do histogram fica estranho também:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atenciosamente,
Arduin

Comment: Nas duas últimas linhas dos dados tem meses `17` e `15`. E falta fechar `)` em `ggplot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso eu tenha entendido corretamente, você quer plotar com um eixo x proporcional ao calendário, correto?

Algo como isso aqui:

[image: Exemplo]

Lembre-se de armazenar a data no seu `data.frame` como class `Date`. Corrigi o mês "15" no exemplo para "12".

```
data <- data.frame(Data=as.Date(c("2016-06-11", "2016-03-05", "2016-01-23", "2016-06-04", "2016-11-30", "2016-12-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                   Frequência=c(3126, 218, 431, 145, 331, 275))
ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = Data,
           y = Frequência)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```